# ERROR: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1688 [character 1689 line 1]

Tags: java, server, udp, client, listener

I have udpclient class, i try to get jsonObject for listen to udpserver, i dont know this code is the right one or no, my udpclient class is like this

```
public class UDPClient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


  URL url = new URL("https://www.instagram.com/ihanan95/?__a=1");
  JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(url.openStream());


      try {
          DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8888); // source socket
          for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
              int port = 8080; // destination port
              byte[] buf = new byte[2024];
              JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
              json.put("count", i);
              InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
              System.out.println(json.toString());
              buf = json.toString().getBytes("UTF8");
              DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
              socket.send(packet);
          }
          socket.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

when i try to run this code, i'm getting error like this

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1688 
[character 1689 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:215)
at UDPClient.main(UDPClient.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's in the error message, the JSON string that you're getting does not start by "{". This means it's not a proper JSON object.

I would log the JSON string (in your case, the tokener) to see what you're obtaining, and see why it's not a valid Json Object.

Comment: thank you very much for reply my post, my json is look like valid with start by "{", you can see that link in my post